# Can I set landscape orientation on implicit intent for a diferent app activity?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, implicit

I am trying to open a pdf file with Android default app for pdf's. I made an Implicit intent and works fine, but I need to set landscape orientation just when pdf is open, not after. I have this line:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This line set landscape when app select menu is open. But when I select "Pdf reader app" it just set portrait again.
The question is: Can I modify anything aspect of an external app from my app? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. as the way an activity or fragment is displayed is under the cotrole of the code. This is not a feature of the system.
So it would not be possible to change the display mode of an activity of an application that you have not developed

Comment: Just that I thought. Thank you!